# On deleting messages, how do I stop them being immediately deleted?

Tags: thunderbird

Using Thunderbird 31.7 (under Ubuntu 14.04) with Imap gmail, when I delete a message it does not go to the Deleted folder, even though that is the setting in Account Settings -> Server Settings. I have no Trash folder so I created one & changed Server Settings accordingly: but that still does not cause deleted messages to go Trash folder. However, the Trash folder is deleted by TB when I restart TB after booting up! Also, it's still present in the appropriate Profile sub-folder.

How do I make deleted messages go to one of Deleted/Trash/any other folder?

Answer (score 0):

I am using TB 31.7 too. I am using IMAP for my professional and for my private account. In Server Settings "move message to folder XY" is activated and for me it works perfectly.

- If your Trash folder is on the mailserver: did you subscribe to the
  corresponding folder? Check this by right clicking on your email
  account in the tree view on the left of TB.
- Or just use one of the
  standard folders that exist on the mailserver (this is depending on
  your providers' setup)

Comment: There is no Trash folder on the mail server (i..e. on [Google Mail] in imap://john.aaron.rose%40gmail.com@imap.googlemail.com/%5BGoogle%20Mail%5D, but there is a folder Bin. I want to use a folder that I have created in Thunderbird e.g. Bin or Deleted but not as per the above.

Comment: Do I understand right that you want to use a "local folder"? This should not matter - you can use any folder that you want being on the server or on your local machine.

Comment: It's a folder that is synced with gmail I.e. it's not a LocalFolder in terms of Thunderbird's understanding.

Comment: Did you try to use the Bin folder of google mail?

Comment: Yes, it works but it's not what I want.

Comment: Yep, I really don't get the message. Could you please explain again what your problem is about and what you want to do.

Comment: I want to have a deleted message move to the Bin folder not a Local Folder nor the Bin folder under (Google Mail). I don't know how to explain any better without sending a screenshot, which AFAIK this website does not allow.

Comment: Again - within Thunderbird you can use a folder on the mailserver or a local folder for deleted messages only! The "bin" folder of your operation system cannot be used.

Comment: This is very difficult to explain without attaching a screenshot, which AFAIK this website does not allow.